# Compose immutable F# map of list of strings

Tags: c#, dictionary, f#, idioms

In C# I could build a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` pretty easy. If I was reading through a large database of items I could do the following:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach(string[] row in data)
   if (!dict.ContainsKey(row[0]))
      dict.add(row[0], new List<string>() { row };
   else
      dict[row[0]].add(row);
```

Now the question is, how do I do this in f# with an immutable `Map<string, string list>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
data
|> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.[0])
|> Map.ofSeq
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more verbose solution which is quite similar to your C# example:

```ml
data |> Seq.fold (fun map row -> 
                 match Map.tryFind row.[0] map with
                 | Some rows -> Map.add row.[0] (row::rows) map
                 | None -> Map.add row.[0] [row] map) Map.empty
```

Comment: I love the uses of `fold`, but Daniel's use of higher order functions is more idiomatic.

Comment: Agree -- this serves as a complementary solution.

Comment: I'm curious, how is this closer? It uses more characters like C#?

Comment: Yes, it's more verbose. `Seq.fold` is similar to `foreach` with an accumulator dictionary.

Comment: [`groupBy`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1274-1296) uses `for`+dictionary and it's already written.

Comment: I appreciate this answer too because it helps me understand how to work with maps in a situation where there is no good high level function to use.

Comment: @Daniel - this solution operates in a similar theoretical way. Yes, it is longer - because this is an almost-imperative algorithm written in a functional language with immutable structures.